# Is this function differentiable in $(1,-1)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have this function: 
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{x \sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}}{x^2+y^2} &\text{if $x^2+y^2-1\geq0$}\\0 &\text{if $x^2+y^2-1\leq0$} \end{cases}$$

I have to say if it differentiable in $(1,-1)$.

I have found that it is differentiable in $(1,-1)$ and I have said that partial derivatives are continuous there, because they are quotient of continuous function.

So, I could say that f is differentiable in $(1,-1)$ but, if I do the limit $$\lim_{\left(h,k\right)\rightarrow\left(0,0\right)}\frac{f\left(x_{0}+h,y_{0}+k\right)-f\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)h-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)k}{\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}}
 $$

I find that it doesn't exist. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you find that the limit does not exist?

Comment: @Siminore I'll recheck it....

Comment: Did you compute correctly the partial derivatives? I get $\partial_1 f(1,-1)=1/2$ and $\partial_2 f(1,-1)=0$.

Comment: @Siminore yes! I have obtained the same results. I have recheck the limit: it exists and is equal to 0... I made an algebra mistake... :( Anyway, can I say that the the function is differenziable in (1,-1) because there the partial derivatives are continuous? they are quotients of continuous functions, aren't they?

Comment: why not do this in polar coordinates?

Comment: @Chilango I always forget to use them! ;)

Comment: @sunrise The test on partial derivatives is always the first thing to do.

Comment: @Siminore with "test on partial derivatives" do you mean "check if they are continuous"?

Comment: @sunrise Yes, precisely!

Comment: @Siminore thanks a lot for your help! :)